# Socket While True Loop Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: python, loops, sockets, while-loop

I want to ask you about while loop in socket works.
The problem is, when i started app, the server is waiting for connections by While True. But if anyone connect, server won't accept another connections. The While True loop freezes.

My Code:

```
import socket
import threading

class Server(object):

    def __init__(self, host="localhost", port=5335):
        """Create socket..."""
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
        self.sock.listen(0)
        self.clients = []
        print("Server is ready to serve on adress: %s:%s..."%(self.host, self.port))

        while True:
            client, addr = self.sock.accept()
            print("There is an connection from %s:%s..."%addr)

            t = threading.Thread(target=self.threaded(client, addr))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

        self.sock.close()

    def threaded(self, client, adress):
        """Thread client requests."""
        while True:
            data = client.recv(1024)
            print("%s:%s : %s"%(adress[0], adress[1], data.decode('ascii')))
            if not data:
                print("Client %s:%s disconnected..."%adress)
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Server()
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the thread properly. You're calling `self.threaded(client, addr)` immediately and then passing the result to `threading.Thread()`.

In other words, this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.threaded(client, addr))
```

... is identical to this:

```
result = self.threaded(client, addr)
t = threading.Thread(target=result)
```

You need to call it like this:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=self.threaded, args=(client, addr))
```